# Pronouncing Karate as kara-te

Tags: pronunciation

Karate is pronounced "kara te" and it can be written 空手 (empty hand) or 唐手 (Chinese hand). 手 is the word for hand and is pronounced "te". Now to the tricky part: 空 means sky/emptiness and it's pronounced "sura". 唐  means Tang/Chinese and it's pronounced "to". Why are both these words pronounced "kara" in kara-te? Why not "sura-te" and "to-te"? I'm confused. Can anyone please help me here?

Comment: 空 is pronounced both as そら (sora, not sura) and as から (kara) as kun-yomi.  The former means "sky"; the later means "empty".

Comment: And 唐 is pronounced as から (kara) as kun-yomi. It meant China, Korea, or any foreign place in earlier times.

Comment: I want to learn Sky Hand martial arts. 

Comment: For examples of other words that use the "kara" reading for these kanji... there's 空回り (karamawari - spinning in place, going in circles) or 唐揚げ (karaage - deep-fried). There are more as well. So, no, it's not unusual for these kanji to be read as "kara."

Comment: Thanks so much for the answers. I'm not familiar with Japanese at all (nor with any other Asian language...). Sorry to insist but is this a correct understanding? 1. 空 - The same exact written word can have two meanings and thus be pronounced in two different ways? 2. 唐 - Kara would fit in perfectly, but google pronouncer and others that I've tried say "to" or something like that. In fact, Sakugawa Kanga, one of the first-ever Karate masters called his style "Tōde" or "to te" in Japanese meaning China and hand. Not "kara te". Am I completely wrong here?

Comment: Thanx Leebo. So, 唐 can be pronounced as "to" OR as "kara" with the same meaning?

Comment: Ok. I have to dive into the way Asian languages are built. It's difficult if you only have the European languages to compare. But now it's much clearer to me :) Thanx a million Leebo. Awesome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about other Asian languages but this is how Japanese happens to be: a lot of kanjis have more than one reading (and meaning). How to find out the reading in each specific case? Well, bad news is that you'll have to memorize this. Sometimes it gets to be almost absurd. Check this out:

- 生 — **nama** — raw; uncooked; fresh
- 生 — **sei** — life; living
- 生 — **ki** — pure; undiluted; raw; crude
- 生 — **iku** — vital; virile; lively​
- 生 — **fu** — area of thick growth (of trees, grass, etc.)​
- 生きる — **i**kiru — to live; to exist
- 生まれる — **u**mareru — to be born
- 生じる — **shou**jiru — to produce; to yield; to cause​
- 生憎 — **ai**niku — unfortunately; sorry, but ...​
- 生る — **na**ru — to bear fruit​
- 生える — **ha**eru — to grow; to spring up; to sprout
- 生業 — **nari**rei — occupation; calling
- 生垣 — **ike**gaki — hedge
- 生い茂る — **o**ijigeru — to grow thickly; to be overgrown; to thrive
- 生毛 — **ubu**ke — downy hair; down; vellus hair; peach fuzz; fluff

Fortunately, this is a rare example. Most of the kanjis have 2-3 readings.